# Postgres table locks during DDL to alter rename table

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, locking, etl, ddl

I have about 5 rather large 100 mil record tables which change significantly each day which need to be accessed for detailed reporting by our APIs. Currently I load data to a stg schema from our dw, then using functions insert those tables with _new, then index them then rename them drop my final target table and rename my _new to the final target table name. I was originally handling this in one function but was getting locks from queries when there were less than 30 connected queries so the function got locked and queries were locked as well. I’m not too familiar with transactions and understand that the DDL commands are locking the tables which makes sense just to sure why the queries are blocking the drop rename or what commands i should use to read without locks. At this point I’ve split the ETL, indexing , and drop rename into 3 separate functions which seems to be working as the ETL and indexing take the longest and the drop rename is occurring in milliseconds. Looking to see if anyone has a better approach or if there is a standard way to do this to avoid locks at all.

Thank you

Comment: It is spelled out in the docs [Explicit Locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html).

Comment: Maybe still not following. Read this doc as well, but assumed the drop would have a higher level access exclusive lock, so the reads would not have dead locked the table drop.

Comment: What makes you think there was a dead lock? They are not that common. Without the code you are using there is really no hope for an answer that is not a guess. Add the code you are using as update to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read without (`ACCESS SHARE`) locks.

If you want to drop one schema and rename the other in a single transaction, you have to make sure that there is no active statement or transaction while the renaming is going on.  One way to achieve that is to kill all other sessions before you start.